# Remove \" from Path converted to string

Tags: c#, replace, tostring, string-literals, fileinfo

I am querying the registry for an ImagePath of a service.  What returns is:

```
"C:\Program Files\App\App.exe"
```

I convert that ToString in my registry function and the result is:

```
"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\App\App.exe\""
```

I need to then create a `FileInfo` object and it is failing due to the illegal characters.

How do I strip the string back down to "C:\Program Files (x86)\App\App.exe" so I can simply state @string in my `FileInfo` initialization.

The easy answer is to not convert it to a string in the first place, however that would change the behavior of my helper function that is widely used.

Code:

```
public static String getRegistryKeyValue(RegistryHive hiveType, String key, String value)
    {
        RegistryKey registryKey;
        if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem == true)
            registryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hiveType, RegistryView.Registry64);
        else
            registryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hiveType, RegistryView.Registry32);

        RegistryKey keyToRead = registryKey.OpenSubKey(key);

        String data = "";
        try
        {
             data = keyToRead.GetValue(value).ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            logger.Error("Unable to get key: " + key + " for value: " + value);
        }
        logger.Info("Getting registry data for: " + key + " with value: " + value + " is: " + data);
        return data;
    }
```

When I call that method and initialize DirectoryInfo, it throws an exception "Illegal characters in path".  With @ or without results in the same exception.

```
DirectoryInfo exe = new DirectoryInfo(@exePath);
```

Comment: `x = x.Replace("\"", "");`

Comment: Where are you seeing that string? My guess is that you're seeing it in the debugger, and it doesn't really have all of those backslashes in. What happens if you print it out onto the console?

Comment: You need to post sample code that shows the problem.

Comment: value = value.Substring(1);

Comment: I have added my code.

Comment: I have resolved this with trim.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

`value = value.Substring(1, value.Length - 2);`

Answer (score 2):

I use the following method to remove unsafe characters from file paths.

```
public static string RemoveIllegalFilenameCharactersFrom(string unsafeString)
    {
        const string illegalCharactersClass = @"[\&\<\>\:/|" + "\"" + @"\?\*]";

        string replaced = Regex.Replace(unsafeString, illegalCharactersClass, "");

        return replaced;
    }
```

If it is truly generating unsafe strings like you say, I don't see any way around it other than to modify the string by removing the unsafe characters.

Comment: Instead of building up your own illegal chars, you could use `Path.GetInvalidPathChars`

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved, I just needed to remove the quotes with value.Trim('\"').

Answer (score 0):

```
"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\App\\App.exe\""
```

is the *regular* C# *string-literal* representation of the following string *value* (i.e. the *raw content*, without syntactic elements), *including* the enclosing `"` chars.:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\App\App.exe"
```

The equivalent *verbatim* string-literal representation is:

```
@"""C:\Program Files (x86)\App\App.exe"""
```

- Note that the `@` prefix only works in *string literals*; it can *not* be applied *variables* the way you attempted.

For such a string to be recognized as a file path, **the *embedded* enclosing `"` chars. must be removed,** which you can do with [`.Trim('"')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Trim)

```
// -> The following *verbatim value*:
//         C:\Program Files (x86)\App\App.exe
"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\App\\App.exe\"".Trim('"')
```

`.Trim('"')` removes (any nonempty run of) `"` characters from both *ends* of the given string value.